# MySQL utf8_czech_ci vs utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I have an application which is mostly based in czech language, that is why we uft8_czech_ci.

Given this example:

```
WHERE `firstName` = 'ales' collate utf8_czech_ci
```

I am unable to find result `aleš` (which is common czech name). When I try this:

```
WHERE `firstName` = 'ales' collate utf8_general_ci
```

It successfuly finds `aleš`. Is the `utf8_czech_ci` definition in MySQL incorrect? I don't want to just blindly start using general_ci.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that š and s are two different letters in CZ alphabet, so that's that's why it's not found when using `utf8_czech_ci` collation.

See also http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_general_ci.european.html and http://collation-charts.org/mysql60/mysql604.utf8_czech_ci.html

Comment: Interesting – do you know who defines whether `t` & `ť` are considered the same and `s` & `š` not? It does not make much sense to me :-)

Comment: There is actually a bug in mysql bug database - https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34371 and also relevant is http://www.evertype.com/alphabets/czech.pdf

Comment: As it is 7 years old, probably it will never be fixed :/

Answer (score 2):

Another exhibit of the ordering for
    utf8 : utf8_czech_ci

```
A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae  az  Æ=æ  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç  cz  Č=č
D=d=Ď=ď  dz  Ð=ð  E=e=È=É=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  ƒ
G=g=ğ=Ģ=ģ  H=h  hz  ch  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ  ij=ĳ  iz  ı  J=j  K=k=Ķ=ķ
L=l=Ļ=ļ  lj=Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ  ll  lz  Ł=ł  M=m  N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz
O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=ò=ó=ó=ô=õ=ö  oe=Œ=œ  oz  Ø=ø  P=p  Q=q  R=r  Ř=ř  S=s=ş  sh  ss=ß  sz
Š=Š=š=š  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm=™  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų  ue  uz  V=v  W=w
X=x  Y=y=Ý=Ý=ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z  zh  zz  Ž=Ž=ž=ž  Þ=þ  µ
```

Versus     utf8 : utf8_general_ci

```
A=a=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae  az  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç=Č=č  ch  cz
D=d=Ď=ď  dz  E=e=È=É=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  G=g=ğ=Ģ=ģ  H=h
hz  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ=ı  ij  iz  J=j  K=k=Ķ=ķ  L=l=Ļ=ļ  lj  ll  lz  M=m
N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz  O=o=Ò=Ó=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=ò=ó=ó=ô=õ=ö  oe  oz  P=p  Q=q  R=r=Ř=ř
S=s=ß=ş=Š=Š=š=š  sh  ss  sz  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų
ue  uz  V=v  W=w  X=x  Y=y=Ý=Ý=ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z=Ž=Ž=ž=ž  zh  zz
Æ=æ  Ð=ð  ×  Ø=ø  Þ=þ  ÷  ĳ  Ł=ł  Œ=œ  ƒ  Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ
```