# Why is collation affecting LIKE matching even with no national characters involved?

Tags: mysql, collation

Issue: The user enters `%%` to search for texts containing two percent signs in succession. The applications converts that into the condition `... LIKE '%\\%\\%%'`. The database returns wrong results.

I managed to narrow the issue down to collation. Tested across several MySQL and MariaDB versions, the two queries below evaluate differently. I tried to read up on the LIKE operator and collations, but couldn't find anything that would explain the difference.

```
SELECT '%' COLLATE utf8_czech_ci LIKE '%\\%\\%%';
```

Result: `TRUE`

```
SELECT '%' COLLATE utf8_general_ci LIKE '%\\%\\%%';
```

Result: `FALSE`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL utf8\_czech\_ci vs utf8\_general\_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639089/mysql-utf8-czech-ci-vs-utf8-general-ci)

Comment: @bodi0, possibly, but percent signs are surely not related to any national alphabet (at least not in the Czech alphabet), are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's just an old bug. I found at least two confirmed reports (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81990 and 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63829) of similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Both collations contains different character sets (utf8_czech_ci / utf8_general_ci):

```
A=a=ª=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae  az  Æ=æ  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç  cz  Č=č
D=d=Ď=ď  dz  Ð=ð  E=e=È=É=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  ƒ
G=g=ğ=Ģ=ģ  H=h  hz  ch  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ  ij=ĳ  iz  ı  J=j  K=k=Ķ=ķ
L=l=Ļ=ļ  lj=Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ  ll  lz  Ł=ł  M=m  N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz
O=o=º=Ò=Ó=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=ò=ó=ó=ô=õ=ö  oe=Œ=œ  oz  Ø=ø  P=p  Q=q  R=r  Ř=ř  S=s=ş  sh  ss=ß  sz
Š=Š=š=š  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm=™  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų  ue  uz  V=v  W=w
X=x  Y=y=Ý=Ý=ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z  zh  zz  Ž=Ž=ž=ž  Þ=þ  µ
```

and

```
A=a=À=Á=Á=Â=Ã=Ä=Å=à=á=á=â=ã=ä=å=Ā=ā=Ą=ą  Aa  ae  az  B=b  C=c=Ç=ç=Č=č  ch  cz
D=d=Ď=ď  dz  E=e=È=É=É=Ê=Ë=è=é=é=ê=ë=Ē=ē=Ĕ=ĕ=Ė=ė=Ę=ę=Ě=ě  F=f  fz  G=g=ğ=Ģ=ģ  H=h
hz  I=i=Ì=Í=Í=Î=Ï=ì=í=í=î=ï=Ī=ī=Į=į=İ=ı  ij  iz  J=j  K=k=Ķ=ķ  L=l=Ļ=ļ  lj  ll  lz  M=m
N=n=Ñ=ñ=Ń=ń=Ņ=ņ=Ň=ň  nz  O=o=Ò=Ó=Ó=Ô=Õ=Ö=ò=ó=ó=ô=õ=ö  oe  oz  P=p  Q=q  R=r=Ř=ř
S=s=ß=ş=Š=Š=š=š  sh  ss  sz  T=t=Ť=ť  TM=tm  tz  U=u=Ù=Ú=Ú=Û=Ü=ù=ú=ú=û=ü=Ū=ū=Ů=ů=Ų=ų
ue  uz  V=v  W=w  X=x  Y=y=Ý=Ý=ý=ý=ÿ=Ÿ  yz  Z=z=Ž=Ž=ž=ž  zh  zz
Æ=æ  Ð=ð  ×  Ø=ø  Þ=þ  ÷  ĳ  Ł=ł  Œ=œ  ƒ  Ǉ=ǈ=ǉ
```

Comment: As I mentioned in response to your comment, why would that affect percent signs?